# Suppress output of stationarity test that is printed to screen

Tags: r, output, statistical-test

How do I get the `stationarity` test from the [`fractal package`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fractal/index.html) in R to not print any output to the screen.

For example, with the `shapiro.wilk` test when setting the result as a variable it does not give any output as follows

```
lg.day.ret.vec <- rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3)

shap.p <- shapiro.test(lg.day.ret.vec)$p.value
```

This is the case for most tests but when I do it for the `stationarity` test I get some output in the r console.

```
library(fractal)

stat.p <- attr(stationarity(lg.day.ret.vec),"pvals")[1]
1
2
3
4
5
6
N = 2609, nblock = 11, n_block_max = 238, dt =     1.0000
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
```

Comment: @user20650 thanks, yes the edit is correct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In fact, you can suppress the output to R console by *rerouting* it. Two methods are available in R *utils*, `sink`, and `capture.output`. Both methods are intended to send output to a file.

Since you want to suppress the output of a single expression, you can use `capture.output`, with `file=NULL` (default). This will **return** your output as a string. To prevent showing this *returned string* in the R console, you can use `invisible`.

The final code can be:

```
library(fractal)

lg.day.ret.vec <- rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3)
shap.p <- shapiro.test(lg.day.ret.vec)$p.value

invisible(capture.output(
    stat.p <- attr(stationarity(lg.day.ret.vec),"pvals")[1]
))
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if not.